# How to increase the size of a single subfigure with pyplot/gridspec?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot 23 graphs in a 6x4 grid, with one figure taking up twice the width of the other figures. I'm using gridspec and my current code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

x = np.arange(0, 7, 0.01)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=6, ncols=4)

for n in range(22):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[n])
    ax.plot(x, np.sin(0.2*n*x))

corrax = fig.add_subplot(gs[22])
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This produces the following:

[image: Figure grid]

I want to increase the width of the rightmost plot in the bottom row so it takes up the remaining space in that row. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use slices to select several positions from the gridspec, e.g. `gs[22:24]`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

x = np.arange(0, 7, 0.01)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=6, ncols=4)

for n in range(22):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[n])
    ax.plot(x, np.sin(0.2*n*x))

corrax = fig.add_subplot(gs[22:24])
corrax.plot(x,np.sin(0.2*22*x), color="crimson", lw=3)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can also slice the gridspec two-dimensionally. E.g. to create a 3x3 grid and make the plot in the lower right corner span two columns and two rows, you could slice like `gs[1:,1:]`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

x = np.arange(0, 7, 0.01)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=3, ncols=3)

for n in range(3):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,n])
    ax.plot(x, np.sin(0.2*n*x))
    if n !=0:
        ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[n,0])
        ax.plot(x, np.sin(0.2*n*x))

corrax = fig.add_subplot(gs[1:,1:])
corrax.plot(x,np.sin(0.2*22*x), color="crimson", lw=3)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Any way to do something similar spanning across both rows and columns? Concretely, I want to make a 3x3 grid, but with one large plot taking up the 4 spaces in the lower right corner and 5 normal plots taking up the remainder of the space.

Comment: Ah, I just manually added subplots with fig.add_subplot(gs[n]) for all n in (0,1,2,3,6), then did the large one with: plt.subplot2grid((3, 3), (1, 1), colspan=2, rowspan=2)

Comment: I updated the answer with a solution to that case as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
#corrax = fig.add_subplot(gs[5,2:])
corrax = fig.add_subplot(6,4,(23,24))
```

both shold work.

- see [examples](https://www.python-course.eu/matplotlib_multiple_figures.php)